# Xamarin - type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to used `Navigation.PushAsync` to go to a new page in my Xamarin Forms application. I have a page called `InvMachineryItem.xaml` in the same folder as the page I am currently on.

In my current page I have a list. When the list is clicked, the new page should open.

Here is my code:

```
     using myCoolApp.Views; //folder with the pages in it

     async void navigateView()
     {
        Page page = new InvMachineryItem();
        await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
     }

     void machineList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
     {
            navigateView();
            //...more stuff
     }
```

The problem is I am receiving an error:

```
The type or namespace name "InvMachineryItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am confused because they are in the same folder, and I am also implementing a `using` statement as well.

For additional context, here is the InvMachineryItem.xaml.cs class

```
namespace myCoolApp.Views.Inventory
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class InvMachineryItem : ContentPage
    {
        List<ListTemplate> viewButtons = new List<ListTemplate>();
        SessionData viewModel;
        public InvMachineryItem ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            viewModel = ViewModelLocator.Session;
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            viewButtons.Add(new ListTemplate("view.png", "View", true, true));
            viewButtons.Add(new ListTemplate("edit.png", "Edit", true, true));
            viewButtons.Add(new ListTemplate("AddMaintenance.png", "Add Maintenance", true, true));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share InvMachineryItem's class? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, one moment

Comment: InvMachineryItem is in myCoolApp.Views.Inventory, you should add that using statement to the stop of the other file, or change them so they're both in the same namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `InvMachineryItem` lives on `myCoolApp.Views.Inventory` namespace, so the fix is you should change the using statement to `using myCoolApp.Views.Inventory`.

Second fix, just in case you want your InvMachineryItem to live inside `myCoolApp.Views`, you need to change the namespace to `myCoolApp.Views.Inventory`and also update the namespace on your XAML.

The first fix is much easier, you should use it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I was silly to assume that if I included the parent folder that it would undersand. I will mark your response as the answer in 1 minute when the timer is over!

Comment: Great! Good luck with your development! :)